# Action="login.php"... POST... страница недоступна HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php

```
action="login.php" method="POST"
```

На локальной машине все работает, но перенес на хостинг...
Когда посылаю `POST` запрос вылазит `HTTP ERROR 500`

В чем может быть проблема?

---

**UPD**

Абсолютно ничего не сделал (только танцы с бубном) и всё само заработало. Что за фигня?

---

**UPD 2**

В логах обнаружил, что проблема однозначно была с подключением к БД. Но тогда каким образом все решилось само по себе? ))

Comment: ну тут либо  код `login.php` давайте, либо бубен. логи смотрите, что там апач пишет.

Comment: @teran Абсолютно ничего не сделал и всё само заработало. странно))

Comment: это бубен тогда 8)

Answer (score 0):

- Проверьте совместимость версий php.
- Проверьте включены ли используемые модули для работы кода в login.php.
- Проверьте подключение к БД.

Если не разберетесь, ждем код.

Comment: тот случай, когда следует писать комментарий вместо ответа.

Comment: Всё само заработало без каких-либо на то причин.

Comment: Проблема была с БД.